# SQL queries not woking in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi i am working on oracel 10g sql 
i have a table name a. [Table definition and query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YubZ5.jpg)
I am trying to execute  but not able to getting the result?

```
select * from a where cname like '[a-z]%';
```

Comment: Dont you get a syntax error here, it should be '[a-z]%' you missed the first '

Comment: The only wildcards that `LIKE` accepts are `%`and `_`. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) instead.

For example, you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cname, '<Your regular expression>');
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell by the documentation, the `like` function won't accept regex-style character ranges. Try `REGEXP_LIKE` instead.